# ng-repeat how to use filetr with 2 parametrer

Tags: angularjs

Here im using ng-repeat as

```
      <tr ng-repeat="d in TranHistory">
 <td>{{d.Quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{d.Qty_Lock}}</td>
     <td>{{d.Balancedcommodity |filter:GetBalance(d.Quantity,d.Qty_Lock)}}</td>
    </tr>
```

im trying to do Sum Operation on **filter:GetBalance**

```
 $scope.GetBalance = function (Quantity,lock) {
            if (Quantity > 0 && lock > 0) {
                var available = Quantity - lock;
                return d.Balancedcommodity = available;
          
        }
    }
```

Here why im not able to update my value
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you do this:

```
<td>{{GetBalance(d)}}</td>
```

and in your js:

```
$scope.GetBalance = function (d) {
       if (d.Quantity > 0 && d.Qty_Lock > 0) {
           var available = d.Quantity - d.Qty_Lock;
           d.Balancedcommodity = available;
           return d.Balancedcommodity;
      }
   return "";
}
```

And if you really wanna use filter: try custom filter like below

```
angular.filter('getBalance', function(){
   return function(d){
      if (d.Quantity > 0 && d.Qty_Lock > 0) {
           var available = d.Quantity - d.Qty_Lock;
           return available;
      }
      return "";
   }
});
```

And in your html you can use it like this:

```
<td>{{d|getBalance}}</td>
```